# Iterate over a $list of unexpanded filemasks

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have a bash script that is run during a software release, to validate that all source files include a copyright & license header.  Every now and then, I have to add a new file extension to it, and consequently my 'find' command is getting a bit unwieldy.  I decided to refactor it somewhat to make it easier to add new file types.  I want to do this by defining a variable `FILEMASKS` that contains a list of file masks.  Conceptually, it looks something like this:

```
FILEMASKS="*.?pp *.[ch] *.sh"
echo FILEMASKS is \'$FILEMASKS\'

for _fs in $FILEMASKS; do
  echo \# find . -iname \'$_fs\'  # debug
          find . -iname \'$_fs\'  # (not really indented this way)
done
```

The output of the above code is not what I expected:

```
FILEMASKS is '*.?pp *.[ch] *.sh'
# find . -iname '*.?pp'
# find . -iname '*.[ch]'
# find . -iname 'check-license.sh'
```

Basically, there are two problems:

1. Only the `echo` lines generate any output; the actual invocations of `find` are silent, indicating that nothing was found that matched.   This is puzzling, since the echo'd version indicates that the `find` command is being constructed exactly how I expect it to be.  (And if I copy-paste that echo output to the shell, it does return a list of files.)
2. <s>The `for` loop is expanding values of $_fs, in cases where there are files in the current directory that match $_fs (such as 'check-license.sh', for '*.sh')   Whereas, my desired outcome is to have all of the file masks in $FILEMASKS make it to my `find` command unexpanded.</s>

**[UPDATE]** I just found a way to solve #2 above:  I remove the `*.` from the beginning of every entry in my `FILEMASKS` variable, and then add it back *in situ* within the `find` command.   So, only #1 remains.  But I'm still interested in seeing other solutions to #2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array for your list of masks to circumvent these issues.

Something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
exts=('*.txt' '*.jpg')

for ext in "${exts[@]}" ; do
  echo "* For mask [$ext]:"
  find . -iname "$ext"
done
```

I get this output (toplevel directory contains a txt and a jpg file, to make sure no early globbing takes place):

```
* For mask [*.txt]:
./b.txt
./bar/a.txt
* For mask [*.jpg]:
./foo/a.jpg
./b.jpg
```

Your problem #1 is this:

```
$ find . -iname '*.txt'
./a.txt
$ find . -iname \'*.txt\'
$ touch "'b.txt'"
$ find . -iname \'*.txt\'
./'b.txt'
```

You're asking `find` to list files that, literally, match `'*.?pp'`, with the single quotes in the filename. (And since the `*` and other globbing chars are not quoted, you'll get globbing by the shell before the argument is passed to `find`.)

Comment: This seems to work; thanks.  But, can you explain the cause of #1?

Comment: @RyanV.Bissell: added a "demo" and explanation.

Comment: Interesting.  I believe I escaped the single-quotes for the -iname argument, because I routinely use single-quotes as such when banging out a `find` command at the shell... but within this script I was finding that the single-quotes were keeping the $_fs from being expanded.  So I thought the escapement would solve the latter problem.. I didn't realize it would make them considered to be part of the filename mask itself.

Comment: Using double quotes instead of single quotes would have solved that part of the problem, but you'd still have your #2 to tackle because pathname expansion (globbing) happens after parameter expansion. That would mean that the `for _fs in $mask ;` will result in `for _fs in file1 file2 ... ;` if there are matches in the current directory. The _quoted_ array expansion fixes that - not sure if there's a trick without the array.